# Create Programmable Route by comparing arrays and state in React

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I want to create a category for different items. from an array, items are printed and those items will create specific route accordingly by comparing to other items in a different array and create a route for that.

FOR THE FIRST ARRAY

```
const categ = ['Sports', 'Entertainment', 'Politics', 'Global']

{ categ.map((category) => {
                return (<NavLink to={`/${categoryLink}`} key={category}>{category}</NavLink>)
            })}
```

(i have no idea how to make the 'categoryLink'

FOR THE SECOND ONE(NOT ACTUALLY AN ARRAY)

```
const debateTwo = store.dispatch(createDebate({
teamOneImg: <img src={Img} />,
teamTwoImg: <img src={Img} />,
startTime: 0,
debateDesc: 'Batman V Superman',
teamOneDesc: 'Batman  ',
teamTwoDesc: 'Superman',
teamOneScore: '50',
teamTwoScore: '50',
category: 'Entertainment',
tags: '#
```

so when I compare both of them a link that shows for the category of 'Entertainment' it should show these items. How should I do that?
Or is there any other way to create a category in React. I am new to it. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to create category in Reactjs. The way you're doing you have to create route and component for each one.

```
const categ = ['Sports', 'Entertainment', 'Politics', 'Global'];
```

- For each item in array or any link you want to create, make a route and components.

  `<Route path="sports" component={Sports} />
  <Route path="entertainment" component={Entertainment} />`

**Or**

```js
{ categ.map((category) => {
  const link = category.toLowerCase();
  return (<Route path=`${link}` component={category} />)
})}
```

You should explicitly create component for each one, and import them with the same name.

**But if you want to load data dynamically for each category:**

- Then create only one route for category like and give it an id or param name like categoryName.

  `<Route path="/category/:categoryName" component={category} />`
- Then create category Component and load data based on id for each category

**imagine this as a category component:**

```js
const categ = ['Sports', 'Entertainment', 'Politics', 'Global']
function Category () {
    // You can access the params (:/categoryName)
    // you provide to route in this.props.params,
    // like this.props.params.categoryName
    const getCategoryData = categ.filter( category === this.props.params.categoryName
    return (
        <div>{
         getCategoryData
        }</div>
)
```

This is a very simple example.I just want to give you an idea.
How to implement category depends on your model implementation not Reactjs library.